# Compile SASS/SCSS files on Heroku in Django app

Tags: django, heroku, sass, static-files, django-compressor

I am getting an error when `DEBUG` is set to `False` or `unset` in **Heroku**, in **Django** app, when I activate logs.

> ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'css/sass/home.css'

Seems that my **SCSS** files are not compiled when I deploy on **Heroku**, while it compiles automatically locally with **django-sass-processor**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that heroku skipps the compiling scss files part, and pass directly to collecting statics so:

**1st step** was to disable collecting static files:

```
heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

**2nd step** is to run a post-compile process:

```
heroku run python manage.py compressscss
```

and then

```
heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

This can be run automatically by overriding the post-compile of python build pack shown here in this post  [Link to a how to create postcompile file](https://vitorbaptista.com/how-to-compile-sass-scss-files-when-deploying-django-to-heroku?fbclid=IwAR2Up6cXvXhoLYFAVhmtr0AX-ezk1DHK9BEykJSuhUD5XwTEFMgUHAECYoc)

Where you create a file in `bin/post_compile` in the root of the app with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cd "$1" || exit 1
python manage.py compilescss --traceback
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --traceback
```

And push to Heroku to apply changes.